# React Monaco Editor layout error, after editor.dispose and editor.getModel().dispose()

Tags: reactjs, monaco-editor

[image]

Unmount callback function called `editor.dispose(); editor.getModel().dispose();`.
While visiting the editor page again, the layout became like this picture.